# launchd crowds syslog with error-messages

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.3 and have some problem with repeated error-messages crowding the

> /var/log/system.log

file.

> Apr 19 15:15:14 pc49 com.apple.launchd[1]: *** process 1 exceeded 500
>   log message per second limit  -  remaining messages this second
>   discarded ***
>
> Apr 19 15:15:44 --- last message repeated 29 times ---
>
> Apr 19 15:15:44 pc49 com.apple.launchd[1]: *** process 1 exceeded 500
>   log message per second limit  -  remaining messages this second
>   discarded ***
>
> Apr 19 15:16:04 --- last message repeated 20 times ---

I guess "process 1" refers to the PID, which then of course is launchd itself, so i can't just kill it. Also, in the last line (15:16:04) it says "last message", but what message does it actually refer to? I don't even know the messages being omitted.

"top -o cpu" btw. tells me that syslogd is using about 90% cpu, although everything runs smoothly, and has produced about 200 million faults since i killed it 2 hours ago where it immediately restarted.

launchd (with pid 1) uses about 45% cpu and counts 2 billion faults so far.

Also PIDs (which are -are they?- assigned in a consecutive manner) are in the tenths of thousands. Since this is supposed to be a local server of some sort, occasional reboots are not so cool. Last reboot (that i know of) was one week ago.

edit: wow have i not looked at this a long time! problem was some while-loop in a php-script if i remember correctly. it could be fixed easily . i'll just leave this here i guess, idk

Comment: I don't want to sound snide, but have you looked at the actual errors?  PID's are typically assigned consecutively, but will loop if the upper limit is reached.  500 errors/sec * 20 = 100k errors/sec.  That's a ton.

Comment: I would love to look at the actual error, but the above quote directly comes from the content of the system.log, without in-between-omissions. As you can see by looking at the time stamps the actual error-message, that above messages refer to, is not written there. Could it be in some other log-file?

Comment: Wow yeah I'm at a loss, sorry.